# Mysqlclient requires MS Visual C++ 10.0 which again requires .Net Framework 4

Tags: python, mysql, django

Trying to install with **pip install mysqlclient**

I am installing MysqlClient in Python virtualenv but installation failed with error

**It requires MS Visual C++ 10.0**

I downloaded it, which again requires .NET Framework 4.
I again downloaded .NET Framework 4, which is giving error that you cannot install .NET Framework 4 as higher version is already installed.

I searched all over the internet there isn't any solution to this problem is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling approximately 24 hrs. I found a solution that will fix this ridiculous problem which has no solution on the whole internet.

While Installing mysqlclient use the following command, and the latest mysqlclient will be installed without any problem.
**pip install --only-binary :all: mysqlclient**

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, wheels were not built for the most current release, but the previous release has them. Try this:

```
pip install "mysqlclient==1.3.12"
```

That will install the previous version, 1.3.12, instead of 1.3.13, which should be fine, unless any of these items are show stoppers: https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/blob/master/HISTORY.rst#whats-new-in-1313

Good luck!